# Unexpected behaviour of code while executing program for specific test cases.(in Java)

Tags: java, logic

Here's a piece of code that I've written to check if the sum of digits and sum of squares of digits of a number are prime,in a given range. If they both are prime, I simply increment the counter, and ultimately I print the counter value.

```
for(int j = lb; j <= ub ; j++)
{
    temp = j;
    do
    {
        sd = sd + (temp%10);
            sosd = sosd + ((temp%10) * (temp%10));
        temp = temp/10;
    }while( temp != 0);
    for(int p = 2; p <= (sd/2) ; p++)
    {
        if( p == sd/2 )
            pf = 0;
        if( sd % p == 0 )
        {
            pf = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int p = 2; p <= (sosd/2) ; p++)
    {
        if( p == sosd/2 )
            pff = 0;
        if( sosd % p == 0 )
        {
            pff = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( pf == 0 && pff == 0 )
        count++;
sd = 0;
sosd = 0;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

All the variables have been properly defined and declared(please bear with the variable names).
The problem is : when I run for lb = 10 to ub = 20, I get count = 4 (which is correct).
But when I run for lb = 1 to ub = 20 , I get count = 3(It is wrong!! And I'm unable to find how this is so,I tried printing individual values only to find that there is something wrong with count and it doesn't increment for the last time. And much to my astonishment, it produces the right answer for the first case that I tested, which is a subset of this case! ).
Please help!

Comment: LOL. When you can't answer, you downvote, as if to show I haven't put an effort into this!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but an "lol" and assuming you were downvoted because someone couldn't answer is a good way to get downvoted even more.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's a bit frustrating to see how people can easily assume that there isn't an effort put into this,that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the two inner `for` loops:

```
for (int p = 2; p <= (sd/2) ; p++)
{
    if( p == sd/2 )
        pf = 0;
```

In some cases, `p` would not necessarily reach `sd/2` which means that the `pf` variable would not reset to 0. Simply try reseting `pf` and `pff` to 0 at the end of your outermost `for` loop:

```
pf = 0;
pff = 0;
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the modification to your code that seems to work fine for me:

```
    for (int j = lb; j <= ub; j++) {
        sd = 0;
        sosd = 0;
        pf = 0;
        pff = 0;
        temp = j;
        do {
            sd = sd + (temp % 10);
            sosd = sosd + ((temp % 10) * (temp % 10));
            temp = temp / 10;
        } while (temp != 0);
        // Check for 1
        if (sd == 1 || sosd == 1) continue;
        for (int p = 2; p <= (sd / 2); p++) {
            if (p == sd / 2) {
                pf = 0;
            }
            if (sd % p == 0) {
                pf = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int p = 2; p <= (sosd / 2); p++) {
            if (p == sosd / 2) {
                pff = 0;
            }
            if (sosd % p == 0) {
                pff = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pf == 0 && pff == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Doesn't work still,takes the count to 6 instead of 3(which should have been 4).

Comment: For `lb=1` and `ub=20`, I'm actually getting 6 which is correct according to your code. However, there is a problem with it since you do not consider the special case of 1. Therefore, your program returns true for `j=1` and `j=10`. You should probably check for 1 separately since it's a special case (perhaps simply checking if `sd` or `sosd` are equal to 1). Taking this into consideration should return the correct result.

Comment: When I just add an extra line of code :
`System.out.println(sd + " " + sosd);`
before the count check `if` statement,I get the following output for `lb=11` and `ub=20`.
`2 2
3 5
4 10
5 17
6 26
7 37
8 50
9 65
10 82
2 4`
Which is correct.(In order from 11 to 20,respectively).
And it prints the same for `lb=1` and `ub=20`. But it simply doesn't increment count for the last case this time, that is at 16.

Comment: Sum of digits of 11 is 2,and sum of square of digits of 11 is also 2, and so on.

Comment: I just edited my post to include code that seems to work fine for me (the result is 4 in both cases - i.e., 10 to 20 and 1 to 20, right?). Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

It would be better and easier to analyze the code with adding proper methods which clearly give a hint on what they are doing. that will remove the need to rely on the global variables in such a dangerous way where they need resetting in the loops, something we tend to forget.

define three methods: one to sum the digits, one to sum the squares of digits and one to check if a number is prime. after that, finding bugs is easier as you will debug single methods.

check the following rewrite:

```
static int sumOfDigits(int number){
      int sum = 0;
      while (number != 0) {
        sum += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
      }

      return sum;
    }


    static int sumOfSquaresOfDigits(int number){
      int sum = 0;
      int digit=0;
      while (number != 0) {
        digit=number % 10;
        sum += digit*digit;
        number /= 10;
      }

      return sum;
    }


    static boolean isPrime(int number) {
      //check if n is a multiple of 2
      if (number%2==0) return false;
      //if not, then just check the odds
      for(int i=3;i*i<=number;i+=2) {
        if(number%i==0)
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

now that those methods are defined, the code becomes like this:

```
  int count=0;
  int lb=1;
  int ub=20;
  for(int j = lb; j <= ub ; j++)
    if ( isPrime(sumOfDigits(j)) && isPrime(sumOfSquaresOfDigits(j)) )
      count++;  

  System.out.println(count);
```

Note: code for summing digits was taken from [here](http://www.javaforstudents.co.uk/Code_snippets/Sum_of_digits_of_a_number) and i modified it to make version for summing squares.

code for checking prime was taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Btw to check for the primality of a number n, you can run the loop upto **sqrt(n) instead of n/2.** This will improve the efficiency for testing larger numbers. sqrt(n) is a stricter bound.

Comment: this is done in the loop already. please note the i*i<=number
so instead of using sqrt() they used i*i. i say they cause it comes from the link provided in final note in the answer.